# How to assign the Scripting.DriveTypeConst in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm tying to get this code to work and for some reason, I can't assign any of DriveTypeConst. The compiler just says "Menthod or Data Member not found"

```
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim objDrv As Drive
Dim enumDrvType As Scripting.DriveTypeConst
Dim enumRemoteDrvType As Long

Set enumRemoteDrvType = Scripting.DriveTypeConst.Remote -- Error here
Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
```

I know I have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime referenced, so I'm not entirely sure why I can't access this. I'm using Access 2010.

Comment: An enum is not an object type, so start by removing the `Set` in the assignment

Answer (score 3):

The TypeLib of the `Scripting` enumerations is a little messed up, as you can see in the Object Browser:

[image: Remote in the Object Browser]

The issue isn't that you can't explicitly specify the namespace of `Remote` - it's that `Remote` isn't ***in*** the `Scripting.DriveTypeConst` namespace.  If you really want/need to you can explicitly declare it like this:

```
Sub Example()
    Dim x As Scripting.DriveTypeConst
    x = Scripting.[__MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0001_0000_0001].Remote
    Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

But, as @TimWilliams points out, enumerations are given global scope in VBA so you only need to fully qualify them if you have something declared in a more local scope with the same name (i.e., if you had a variable in your procedure named `Remote`).

Comment: Curious... why the heck would the enum be listed under DriveTypeConst then?

Comment: It's just how the MIDL is written for the typelib (no clue why).  `DriveTypeConst` is just an alias for  `__MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0001_0000_0001`.  The relevant entry in the typelib is `typedef [public] __MIDL___MIDL_itf_scrrun_0001_0000_0001 DriveTypeConst;`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
 enumRemoteDrvType = Remote
```

You should get intellisense as you're typing the enum

Comment: I got it. The intellisense wasn't coming up so I was getting confused. Combined with removing the Set as you suggested, this should be it: `Dim enumRemoteDrvType As DriveTypeConst enumRemoteDrvType = Scripting.DriveTypeConst.Remote`. Thanks.

Comment: this should be it, actually: `Dim enumRemoteDrvType As DriveTypeConst enumRemoteDrvType = Remote`. Thanks.